# Where to get source code of an .so library file?

Tags: ros, c++, source

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everybody

I am looking for the source file of libgazebo_ros_bumper.so. Where can I find it?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/243998/where-to-get-source-code-of-an-.so-library-file?/) by [Masoud](https://answers.ros.org/users/26841/masoud/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2016-09-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[this](https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs/blob/kinetic-devel/gazebo_plugins/src/gazebo_ros_bumper.cpp) one for kinetic

[this](https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs/blob/indigo-devel/gazebo_plugins/src/gazebo_ros_bumper.cpp) one for indigo

Is that what you meant?

Anyway, just navigate through the github page

---

Originally posted by [alienmon](https://answers.ros.org/users/27685/alienmon/) with karma: 582 on 2016-09-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Masoud](https://answers.ros.org/users/26841/masoud/) on 2016-09-19**:
Thanks a lot...

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-09-20**:
@Masoud: could you please accept the answer by @alienmon by ticking the checkmark to the left of it? That will more clearly mark this question as answered then if we just close it.

Thanks.